find value from dfa in dfb$col1 and report corresponding value in dfb$col2
I have two large dfs:
 lookup_val <-c(30911003,23284867,31383855)
 other_dat <-c(D,E,G)

 dfa <- data.frame(lookup_val,other_dat)

 dfb <- data.frame(returnme = c(100,200,300,400,500),
                      checkme = I(list(c("22915123;23284867;28631094"),
                                 c("24828645;22915123;23284867;22516463;25650693"),
                                 c("24898660;18978948;25153701;31073629;23545424"),
                                 c("30911003;28209725;24990881"),
                                 c("30911003;28802038")))
                         )

what's the most elegant way to search for a value in dfa$lookup_val in dfb$checkme then return the corresponding value in dfb$returnme?
I can
value <- grep(as.character(30911003), dfb$checkme, value = TRUE)
 

which returns
#[1] "30911003;28209725;24990881" "30911003;28802038"  

but what I want is to return 400,500, which are the unique ids for those two lists.
The number of lists returned by the grep statement will be variable, so it seems not trivial to use as an output to grep again within dfb. Using filter to retrieve whole rows from dfb seems really clunky, as ultimately I want to loop over the whole column dfa$lookup_val.
What am I missing? I must be missing something.
thanks

Something like this lapply(lookup_val, \(x) dfb[grep(x, dfb$checkme),"returnme"])?

left_join(dfa |> mutate(across(lookup_val, as.character)), dfb |> separate_longer_delim(checkme, ";"),  join_by(lookup_val == checkme))

^separate_longer_delim from tidyr btw
